# A Batch File which contains a Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes, ksh, lotusscript

Is it possible to run a batch file containing a lotus script? Would it also be possible to include a lotus script and then another language for example ksh's? If yes then could you please give me some samples or tutorials on how to do it?

What I need to do is this:

- There is already an existing batch file which contains a ksh's that updates the value in an excel files every time it is executed.
- What I need to do is include two new functions, first I need to download the excel file from a rich text in a document of lotus notes, then run the functions above written in ksh's after that
- I need to re-upload it or update the excel file which is in the lotus notes document. I used lotus script for the added functionality.

I also don't know how to use or create ksh's and batch files. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would turn around the logic: why not use a scheduled LotusScript or Java- Agent, detach the file from the richtextitem and then run the ksh from there (e.g. using the Shell- Command of LotusScript)...
That way you can code the stuff you need in the languages that are best for your purpose. You could even attach the ksh to a configuration document and detach it on the fly Or build the ksh completely on the fly (with write commands)... That makes this solution replicate to any number of servers without having to distribute your ksh to each of them...

Comment: Hi Torsten,, I see, I didn't thought about using the shell command of lotus script or even the "fly" because maybe I don't know anything about them yet.. I haven't tried those yet,, but know that I know that there is something in the lotus script that can execute shell command and/or ksh's. 

Though I have another question regarding that,, if I am not mistaken scheduled agents usually runs in the server right? so what if that agent is being run on the different computers.. so the way to solve it is to manually trigger the agent right? or is there another way?.. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can schedule the agent for being started regularly for instance ever hour or day or week at a certain time.  You can also define on which server the agent will be executed.

Comment: There is also a possibility to run scheduled agents on a Notes- Client. This has to be enabled (in the Preferences) and of course the notes client has to run at that time. But it IS possible.

Comment: Thanks Knut and Torsten, I just created a simple agent that would be manually triggered by the user.. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

LotusScript runs only within a scripting host engine provided by IBM Lotus, but LotusScript isn't the only way to access Lotus Notes data.

You haven't said what platform you are running ksh on.  You mention that you are operating on Excel files, so if you are running your scripts on Windows it may be possible for you to use the Lotus Notes COM classes. Those classes are almost exactly the same as the back-end classes that you would have available in LotusScript, but I have no idea whether any version of ksh (not to mention whatever version you are using) supports the CreateObject call or any other way to access COM classes.

However, a ksh script can certainly run Java programs, and there are Java classes for Lotus Notes that are (again) almost exactly the same as the back-end classes that you would use in LotusScript.  It seems to me that the obvious thing for you to do is write a small Java program to retrieve the file from the Domino server, and another Java program to re-upload it after.  Then have your script run the program to do the download, run the commands to modify the Excel data, and then run the program to do the upload.

Comment: Hi Richard,, thanks for the information,, actually I really have zero background on ksh script.. but this information would be a lot of help.. For now though I'll try with what torsten suggested I think it would be easier for me since I am more familiar with the lotus script.. but If I can't do it then I'll try this one,, Thanks a lot richard.